# Connecting HAML simple_form with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have something like this:

```
  = f.input :payment_date, as: :date
  = f.input :tuitor, as: :boolean, label: 'Tuitor payment'
```

and I want use on this a simple JavaScript like this:

```
costam = ->
if document.getElementById('datet').checked is true
  document.getElementById('pdate').disabled = false
else
  document.getElementById('pdate').disabled = true
return
```

How I can put 'datet' and 'pdate' in my HAML form? I was trying options like

```
:id => "pdate"
```

or

```
id: :pdate
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use [`input_html`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage):

```
= f.input :payment_date, as: :date, input_html: { id: "datet" }
= f.input :tuitor, as: :boolean, label: 'Tuitor payment', input_html: { id: "pdate" }
```

---

In regards your javascirpt, you'd be much better using variables:

```
costam = ->
  datet = document.getElementById('datet')
  pdate = document.getElementById('pdate')

  pdate.disabled = !datet.checked
```

You can see a **working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwf7vues/)** here:

```
var changer = function() {
  var datet, pdate;
  datet = document.getElementById('datet');
  pdate = document.getElementById('pdate');
  pdate.disabled = !datet.checked;  
};

$(document).ready(changer);
$("#datet").on("change", changer);
```

Comment: It's not working. All I am getting by this it's unlickable, unactive checkbox.

Comment: IMO JavaScript cannot detect "datet" as my :payment_date. For checkbox input_html is working fine but there is a problem with date.

Comment: Have you got Turbolinks? Is your `.on` event firing?

Comment: Yes. Also if I do something like $('*').attr 'disabled', true after $(document).on 'click', #'pdate' it's disabling all elements. So event is working fine.

Comment: So have you got the `ids` in the HTML?

Comment: I have not. Only something like this: <select id="student_payment_date_1i" name="student[payment_date(1i)]">
I tried using name or select id as selector but it is also not working.

Comment: Okay if you haven't got the `id`s, that's likely the issue, not the JS. Do either of the inputs have `id`s assigned?

Comment: Yes. Only this date doesn't have id.